# Extension of conference/business visa for 17 days instead of 10 days for South Africa - New Application?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, south-africa, visa-extensions

I have been granted a visa for conference 10 days but both my flight and the conference will run much longer - 17 days to be exact. I have tried calling the consulate-general office to talk to somebody but that isn't working. There is an e-mail address sacgmumbai@saconsulate.in but am doubtful as I had already put a query and it bounced back hence that e-mail address is worthless. The domain is not found.

I had put both in my typed cover-letter and in the form itself that I need the visa for 17 days.

Now if I put a new, fresh application should I just add a cover letter stating the extension (which had got overlooked in the first application) or need to give all papers from scratch ?

Comment: So, you asked for a visa for 17 days and they gave you a visa for 10 days? Now you are unable to contact them - is that right? @shirish

Comment: contact the consulate, right. It seems everything goes through VFS. There doesn't seem to be a direct way to contact with them and VFS is somewhat un-co-operative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to go to VFS office with your pasport, a cover letter stating that the visa needs to be corrected, sharing additional details or any details which prove why the visa given was wrong and what correction is required.

Make sure that the correction you need is spelled out both in letters and numbers (if its dates) .

Make sure to use BOLD and LARGE letters to emphasize the changes you want.

VFS doesn't charge you for this service and is inclusive of the charges you had already paid before.